# Python 2 and 3 metaclass compatibility when kwargs are used

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, metaclass

I am making a metaclass where I customize the `__new__` method to customize how the new class will be created according to the provided values in `kwargs`. This probably makes more sense in an example:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, kwargs):
        # do something with the kwargs...
        # for example:
        if 'foo' in kwargs:
            kwargs.update({
                'fooattr': 'foovalue'
            })
        return super(FooMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, kwargs)
```

My problem is how can I make this compatible for both Python 2 and 3. [Six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) is a great compatibility library however it does not solve my problem. You would use it as:

```
class FooClass(six.with_metaclass(FooMeta, FooBase)):
    pass
```

This does not work because six creates a new base class by using the given metaclass. Below is the six's code ([link](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/2f26b0b44e7e5b2e5ed41a286c222c210d96fcba/six.py?at=1.3.0#cl-404)) (as of 1.3):

```
def with_metaclass(meta, base=object):
    return meta("NewBase", (base,), {})
```

As a result, my `__new__` method will be called without any `kwargs` hence essentially "breaking" my function. The question is how can I accomplish the behavior I want without breaking the compatibility for both Python 2 and 3. Please note that I don't need Python 2.6 support so if something is possible for only Python 2.7.x and 3.x I am fine with that.

*Background*

I need this to work in Django. I want to create a model factory metaclass which depending on the model attributes will customize how the model is created.

```
class ModelMeta(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, kwargs):
        # depending on kwargs a different model is constructed
        # ...

class FooModel(six.with_metaclass(ModelMeta, models.Model):
    # some attrs here to be passed to the metaclass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right, there is no problem and it already works.  Did you actually check whether your metaclass has the desired effect?  Because I think it already does.

The class returned by `with_metaclass` is not meant to play the role of your class FooClass.  It is a dummy class used as the *base class* of your class.  Since this base class is of metaclass FooMeta, your derived class will also have metaclass FooMeta and so the metaclass will be called again with the appropriate arguments.

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # do something with the kwargs...
        # for example:
        if 'foo' in attrs:
            attrs['fooattr'] = 'foovalue'
        return super(FooMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
class FooBase(object):
    pass
class FooClass(with_metaclass(FooMeta, FooBase)):
    foo = "Yes"

>>> FooClass.fooattr
'foovalue'
```

Incidentally, it is confusing to call the third argument of your metaclass `kwargs`.   It isn't really keyword arguments.  It is the `__dict__` of the class to be created --- that is, the class's attributes and their values.  In my experience this attribute is conventionally called `attrs` or perhaps `dct` (see e.g., [here](http://pythoncentral.org/how-metaclasses-work-technically-in-python-2-and-3/) and [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/14/python-metaclasses-by-example/)).

Comment: You are right. The issue turned out to be related to Django and how I implemented my custom login within the `__new__`. I just blamed the issue on compatibility. Thanx for clarifying the situation.